# Search function through XML file with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have this XML file that I need to be searched and read. You have to be able to search for part strings and with multiple fields. When the search is done it shall give you all the data in the file with just a standard ASP.NET UI!

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            const string FILENAME = @"c:\users\andre\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\DataSource\books.xml";

            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

                var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new
                {
                    id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                    author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                    genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                    price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                    date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                    description = (string)x.Element("description")
                }).ToList();
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Fibonacci()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Sök</h2>
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Sök"/>
```

Comment: This seems like a question you would get as homework. Plus you do not give anything you have tried.

Comment: Look again please, this is what I have tried. But I do not know what to return to the view so the data can be displayed and searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication82
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                description = (string)x.Element("description") 
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might I remind you that I am using a ASP.NET MVC application? There is no Main method here, could you please edit?

Comment: Might we remind  you that an ASP.NET MVC application is written in the same language as a C# Program. This will give you a *hint* at what you need to do, not do it for you.

Comment: I just debugged and I saw that the books are being read, but how do I make it search able and displayed in HTML?